# Dynamic form and DB

Tags: php, database, postgresql

Good morning, I have a problem with inserting files in a database.
I'm using Postgresql.
This is the structure of my database:

> prenotazione (id,nome_rich,cogn_rich,email_rich,oggetto_rich)
>
> interni (id,nome_int,cogn_int,email_int)
>
> esterni (id,nome_est,cogn_est,email_est)

Basically I have to give the possibility to insert the desired number of participants (with respective name, surname, email).
When I try to insert them into the database I get an error in :

> 35) $result = pg_query($conn, $query2 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource

and

> 50) $result = pg_query($conn, $query3 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource

this is my code:

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Prenotazione Videoconferenza</title>
<!-- INIZIO SCRIPT AGGIUNTA DINAMICA -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add1").click(function(e){

      var val1 =$("#n1").val();
      for(var i=0;i<val1;i++){
      $("#start").append($("#first").clone());
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add2").click(function(){

      var val2 =$("#n2").val();
      for(var i=0;i<val2;i++){
      $("#start2").append($("#first2").clone());
      }
    });
});
</script>
<!-- FINE SCRIPT AGGIUNTA DINAMICA -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

Inserire i dati richiesti:<br><br>
<div class="form">
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<b> Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br>
Nome:<input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br>
Cognome:<input type="text" name="surname" size="20"><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="email" size="20"><br>
Oggetto Conferenza:<br><textarea name="testo" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>

<br>
<b>Partecipanti Interni</b>
<br>
<br>
<div id="start">
    <div id="first">
      Nome:<input type="text" name="iname[]" size="20"><br> 
      Cognome: <input type="text" name="isurname[]" size="20"><br> 
      Email: <input type="email" name="iemail[]" size="20"><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
 Numero partecipanti interni:
 <input type="text" id="n1" value="1"><br>

 <button><a href="#" id="add1">Aggiungi partecipante</a></button>



<br>
<b>Partecipanti Esterni</b>
<br>
<br>
Numero partecipanti Esterni:
 <input type="text" id="n2" value="1"><br>

 <button><a href="#" id="add2">Aggiungi partecipante</a></button>

  <div id="start2">
    <div id="first2">
      Nome:<input type="text" name="ename[]" size="20"><br> 
      Cognome: <input type="text" name="esurname[]" size="20"><br> 
      Email: <input type="email" name="eemail[]" size="20"><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="Invia" > 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## input.php

```
<?php

$conn = @pg_connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=123456789");

if(!$conn) {
    die('Connessione fallita !<br />');
} else {
    echo 'Connessione riuscita !<br />';
}

// Richiedente
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$testo = $_POST['testo'];

//inserting data order
$query1 = "INSERT INTO prenotazione (id,nome_rich, cogn_rich, email_rich,oggetto_rich) VALUES (1,'$name','$surname', '$email','$testo')";
//execute the query here
$result = pg_query($conn, $query1 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource
// Interni
$query = "";
if( !empty( $_POST['iname'] ) ) {

    foreach( $_POST['iname'] as $key => $iname ) {

        $isurname = empty( $_POST[$key]['isurname'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['isurname'];
        $iemail = empty( $_POST[$key]['iemail'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['iemail'];
        $query .= " ( '$iname', '$isurname', '$iemail' ) ";
    }
}
if( !empty( $query ) ) {

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO interni (nome_int, cogn_int, email_int) VALUES ".$query;
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query2 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource
}
// Esterni
$query = "";
if( !empty( $_POST['ename'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['ename'] as $key => $ename ) {
        $esurname = empty( $_POST[$key]['esurname'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['esurname'];
        $eemail = empty( $_POST[$key]['eemail'] ) ? NULL : $_POST[$key]['eemail'];
        $query .= " ( '$ename', '$esurname', '$eemail' ) ";
    }
}

if( !empty( $query ) ) {

    $query3 =  "INSERT INTO esterni  (nome_est, cogn_est, email_est) VALUES  " . $query;
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query3 ); //if you are using pg_query and $conn is the connection resource
}
?>
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: Check the manual, multiple rows are separated by commas when you insert them. And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: What i should check??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the resulting syntax of your insert statements. A multiple insert should be like this

```
INSERT INTO interni (nome_int, cogn_int, email_int) VALUES 
('Nome1', 'Cognome1', 'email1')
, ('Nome2', 'Cognome2', 'email2')
, ...
, ('NomeN', 'CognomeN', 'emailN')
```

Beware of the comma between the tuples, in your code you are concatenating rows without separating them with commas.
Also, as suggested in comment, you are subject to SQL injection attacks, you should sanitize your input before storing it in the database.

edit: My point is that if you have more than one row to insert, you have to concatenate the tuples by using commas.
In your code, replace all the

```
$query .= " ( '$iname', '$isurname', '$iemail' ) ";
```

with

```
$query .= ", ( '$iname', '$isurname', '$iemail' ) ";
```

Of course, the first row to be inserted should not start with the comma, which means you have to revise your code to check whether the user is adding just one row or more than one.